# On buttonClick refresh the table with the new rows added

Tags: vaadin

I have created a table and a button. On click of that button i need to add the row. 
For that i have used `buttonClick` method in which i am adding a row in the Table.

The problem is that the row in added to the table (I can see in the logs), 
but the screen becomes blank with just the button displayed.

If I exit and navigate again to the screen, then i can see the new row added.

How can i see the new row added immeditalety once added.

Comment: How are you adding the row? To the table, to the container? As ever, seeing the code would help us to help you.

Comment: Thanks Charles... The issue is resolved... just added the table to the container once the row is added on the buttonClick...

Comment: user1225344: Please provide some code and the solution you used. It would help others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some code would probably help to further see what might be wrong, but I would also recommend you to call the following code line directly after you have added a table row.

```
yourTable.setContainerDataSource(yourTable.getContainerDataSource());
```

This will update the datasource for your table and force a repaint. If you provide some code maybe more help can be provided

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary since Table implements Container.ItemSetChangeListener (and Container.PropertySetChangeListener) which listens the container for changes and updates itself accordingly. I believe the OP's code is missing something critical..

Comment: That is true, I was not aware that the new data was added to the container i thought he/she only added it to a backing model and when a page reload came the table data source picked up the new collection with added items.

Answer (score 0):

Using IndexedContainer to add new row in table during button click..

Example

```
Create IndexedContainer
-----------------------
private IndexedContainer getTblTerminals(IndexedContainer container) 

{

container.removeAllItems();

container.addContainerProperty("Terminal_Id", String.class, defaultValue);

g_TermialPojo=ws.readAll();

for(Terminal pojo:g_TermialPojo)

{


Object itemId=container.addItem();

strTid=String.valueOf(pojo.getTid());


            container.getContainerProperty(itemId,"Terminal_Id").setValue(strTid.toString());


        }

        return container;

}


//To add indexedcontainer in your table
-------------------------------------------

Example



        table.setContainerDataSource(getTblTerminals((IndexedContainer)table.getContainerDataSource()));


table.setImmediate(true);
```